# LISTAGG function gives me duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Each district # in this query corresponds with more than one state. The LISTAGG is great for concatenating the list of states per each district # , however it is giving me duplicate states. How can I fix this? I should add that the reason why I get duplicates is because the number of retail stores per each district , so I have multiple stores within a number of states within each district. But I'd like to see if there is a way to just get unique states...

```
SELECT  distinct DISTRICT_NBR,
        LISTAGG( str_state_abbr, ',') 
          WITHIN GROUP (order by str_state_abbr) AS States
from DIM_LOCATION
where DISTRICT_NBR in (1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 50, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 100, 101, 102, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 130, 131, 134, 135, 136, 140, 143, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 163, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 184, 185, 186, 188, 189, 190, 191, 193, 194, 195, 196, 198, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 221, 222, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 258, 259, 260, 261, 263, 266, 267, 268, 270, 271, 274, 275, 276, 277, 282, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 297, 300, 302, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 310, 311, 313, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 330, 351, 352, 354, 355, 358, 359, 362, 364, 365, 366, 367, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373
)
and STR_STATE_ABBR is not null
group by DISTRICT_NBR
order by DISTRICT_NBR
```

Comment: Get rid of duplicates before applying LISTAGG. `WITH DAT AS(SELECT UNIQUE ROWS) ....SELECT LISTAGG..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  district_nbr,
        listagg( str_state_abbr, ',')         
          within group (order by str_state_abbr) as states          
from (select distinct district_nbr, str_state_abbr from dim_location
       where district_nbr in (1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 50, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 100, 101, 102, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 130, 131, 134, 135, 136, 140, 143, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 163, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 184, 185, 186, 188, 189, 190, 191, 193, 194, 195, 196, 198, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 221, 222, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 258, 259, 260, 261, 263, 266, 267, 268, 270, 271, 274, 275, 276, 277, 282, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 297, 300, 302, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 310, 311, 313, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 330, 351, 352, 354, 355, 358, 359, 362, 364, 365, 366, 367, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373)
         and str_state_abbr is not null
) 
group by district_nbr
order by district_nbr;
```

Comment: With clause for the subquery would look neat and also good when used multiple times.